# Check Search From and Search To date beetwen Deal From date and Deal to Date in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

i have a table as following.

```
DealID        DealTitle   DealStart_Date           DealEnd_Date
1             A           2017-05-01 00:00:00      2017-05-05 00:00:00
2             B           2017-05-02 00:00:00      2017-05-06 00:00:00
3             C           2017-05-03 00:00:00      2017-05-07 00:00:00
4             D           2017-05-04 00:00:00      2017-05-08 00:00:00
5             E           2017-05-05 00:00:00      2017-05-09 00:00:00
```

Now on search from i am searching the data using two date

```
Deal From : 2017-05-08 00:00:00
Deal To   : 2017-05-15 00:00:00
```

According to logic it should be return the `DealID 4 and 6`

Query i have used is

**`SELECT * FROM dealofday WHERE '2017-05-02 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-05 00:00:00' BETWEEN DealStart_Date AND DealStart_Date ORDER BY DealID ASC`**

i have tried the beetween query but didnt worked. how can i overcome this.

Comment: mysql or (MS)SQL-Server. Please delete unrelated tags

Comment: Your Syntax is wrong. It must be <column Name> <Operator> <value> AND <column Name> <Operator> <value>

Comment: SELECT * FROM dealofday WHERE DealStart_Date   BETWEEN '2017-05-02 00:00:00' AND 2017-05-15 00:00:00 ORDER BY DealID ASC

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to find any form of *overlap* between the ranges stored in your table and the search range you're providing, a simple pair of comparisons suffices:

```
SELECT * FROM dealofday
WHERE '2017-05-02 00:00:00' < DealEnd_Date AND
      DealStart_Date < '2017-05-05 00:00:00'
ORDER BY DealID ASC
```

Or, to put it in English - two periods overlap if the first starts before the second ends *and* the second starts before the first ends.

You can adjust the `<` for `<=`, depending on whether the end points are inclusive or exclusive and whether two periods which exactly *abut*<sup>1</sup> are considered to be overlapping.

---

<sup>1</sup>One period starts at the exact point in time at which the other ends.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I'd do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM dealofday
WHERE DealStart_Date > '2017-05-02 00:00:00'
AND DealEnd_Date < '2017-05-15 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the Solution

**`SELECT * FROM dealofday WHERE DealStart_Date BETWEEN '2017-05-08 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-15 00:00:00' OR DealEnd_Date BETWEEN '2017-05-08 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-15 00:00:00'`**

Comment: I assume you intended to use `05-02` for the first date in both `between`s? Also, this won't return rows where the deal starts before `05-02` and ends after `05-05`. Was it your intention to exclude those?

Comment: Damien ..bro i need the data Like if from date and to date of searching is the beetwen date of deal start date and deal end date

Comment: This query will match deals that *start* during your search period and/or *end* during that period, but will not match deals that start *before* your period and end *after* your search period. I was trying to check whether that was your intention.

Comment: OH NO ! u right !! how can cover those which start before and end after search period

Comment: My answer covers all of these scenarios.